# Como crio um diretorio "asset" no VSCode em um projeto Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estou começando a aprender o Flutter e , preciso criar um diretório "assets" na raiz do projeto flutter no VSCode, mas não consigo, só me da a opção de criação de novos Arquivos e novas pastas.

se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço!

Comment: Oi Marcio, tenta trazer mais detalhes de como você tenta realizar essa criação

Comment: eu criei uma pasta, mas ela é criada como um subpasta e não como uma pasta raiz, e nãp consegui fazer funcionar, mesmo adequando o pubspec_yaml, colocando o caminho, ai o flutter não buscou as imagens

Answer (score 2):

Basta criar uma pasta e nomear ela como assets.

Lembrando que no Flutter você precisa editar o arquivo pubspec.yaml adicionando o nome da pasta lá e cuidado com a identação senão dá problema:

```
# To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/cifrao.png
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

Você também vai precisar de uma extensão chamada Pubspec assist. No Android Studio existe um botão para atualizar as dependências mas no VS Code não tem.